# Store an object in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I plan to save some objects into a database using Entity Framework code first, so I create the classes and generate the database from that.

The files I store are the following:

- An HTML file
- and a .mview file.

These two are exported using Marmoset Viewer. I plan to store them as `object` type. All I need to do is copy them to folders (and add a new one to the database).

My question is: is this way, going with an `object` type doable? Or do I have to change something?

The HTML file will be opened using a WebBrowser control. It works, but so far I haven't made the database just yet.

Comment: If both files are simply text, you can use `string`, if not I'd use `byte[]`.

Comment: The html file is indeed text, though I will need its file name as well. 
The other though, its type is `.mview` as I wrote, I don't have to manage it, just move it somehow. 
So in case I misunderstood something, **in c# code** I shall use a `byte[]` ? So not in the data tables

Comment: `varbinary` for the data table

Comment: Thanks. 
So I can read a file from disk e.g. (that mview file) into an array of bytes? (binary formatter maybe?) I might be missing something, So the issue is that AFAIK c# doesn't understand this .mview. I can just read it into a byte array? :D

Comment: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes` should do it

Comment: Didn't even know that exists :D 
Well the question was about storing an unknown file and you answered it. 
Could you convert a comment to an answer so I can accept/upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entities, use `byte[]` for storing binary files. Your matching table column types should be `varbinary`.

You can use [System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to load your entity's property.